# Connect the view of different name to a HttpGet method in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

The code is pretty simple. I have a controller called `Contact` that has a method `ReviewAddContactPage` (HttpGet):

```
namespace ContactPageWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ReviewAddContactPage ()
        {
            return View("index");
        }
    }
}
```

which basically returns the view of `Index` (a page that is asking a user to enter some contact information like name, surname etc.):

```
@model Contact

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddData", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))

{
    <form method="post">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger small-error"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- Surname -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Surname"></label>
            <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Email"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- Sex -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Sex"></label>
            <input asp-for="Sex" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Sex" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <!-- Date of Birth -->
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
            <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ResultMessage))
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                @ViewBag.ResultMessage
            </div>
        }

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 150px">Add</button>
        <a asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back
        </a>
    </form>
}
```

In the code I provided it is going to work correctly, basically when you click in a navigation bar "add information" on webpage it will direct it to `ReviewAddContactPage` method that will then return the view of index.

What I want to do is to route `ReviewAddContactPage` method and `Index.cshtml` view by default, so I want my method to be like this:

```
namespace ContactPageWeb.Controllers
{
    public class ContactController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ReviewAddContactPage ()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, without specifying a view name in return function, I want my method to return the `Index.cshtml` by default, even though the method and view have different names.

Is there some way to do it without changing the method? I want it to be exactly the one as above.

Comment: Could you change the name of Index.cshtml to ReviewAddContactPage.cshtml?

Comment: well I could and it will solve a problem just like with return("Index"), but that's not the purpose of my question.

Comment: Hi @CalvinM., what's the version of asp.net mvc you use? You can try to define an ActionFilter.

Comment: @CalvinM. What's the driver behind it?  This approach could make it a little harder for another developer to support later.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not specifying the view name in the `return View()` inside the `ReviewAddContactPage` action method then it's working as an equivalent of `return View(nameof(ReviewAddContactPage))`.

Therefore, if you want to render the `Index` your can change your action method to `Index`:

```cs
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and define the following `"ReviewAddContactPage"` route:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ReviewAddContactPage",
    url: "{controller}/ReviewAddContactPage",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "Index"}
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could custom an ActionFilter to make sure always return Index view like below:

```
public class SetDefaultViewNameAttributeFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Index"
        };
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Be sure register the filter in Program.cs(or Startup.cs):

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<SetDefaultViewNameAttributeFilter>();
});
```

**Notes:** This only works fine in your current scenario which you return view without any model.